# Teechart Linear Gauge Duplication of axis title for multiple gauges on single chart

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, teechart

I am evaluating Teechart.Net (v4.13.12.13) for Xamarin Android (v4.12) to determine suitability for a project that requires the use of gauges to present data and I've come across a few issues that I haven't been able to figure out:

1. I would like to add a number of linear gauges to a chart, each with a unique title, but it seems the axis title assigned to the last gauge that was added to the chart is applied to all gauges in the chart. Am I setting the wrong property (LinearGauge.Axis.Title.Text) or is there some other way to assign unique titles to the linear gauges. The other apparent option would be to add a separate chart for each gauge, but that doesn't seem right. In the image below, I need to show two distinct temperatures but both are labelled the same.
2. I created a circular gauge and enabled the embedded numeric gauge. However, no matter what I try I cannot get any text displayed in the numeric gauge. It is drawn inside the gauge, but no text. I've set CircularGauge.NumericGauge.Chart.AutoRepaint to true, then false and manually repainted, all without success. Is this a bug? I tried the same code with Teechart.Net for Winforms and it works OK so I'm having doubts about the Teechart release for Xamarin.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add a number of linear gauges to a chart, each with a
>   unique title, but it seems the axis title assigned to the last gauge
>   that was added to the chart is applied to all gauges in the chart. Am
>   I setting the wrong property (LinearGauge.Axis.Title.Text) or is there
>   some other way to assign unique titles to the linear gauges. The other
>   apparent option would be to add a separate chart for each gauge, but
>   that doesn't seem right. In the image below, I need to show two
>   distinct temperatures but both are labelled the same.

This is by design. Gauges use standard chart axes (left and bottom). Each chart has one set of axes and hence the title is being overwritten. Adding separate charts would be the recommendation.

> I created a circular gauge and enabled the embedded numeric gauge.
>   However, no matter what I try I cannot get any text displayed in the
>   numeric gauge. It is drawn inside the gauge, but no text. I've set
>   CircularGauge.NumericGauge.Chart.AutoRepaint to true, then false and
>   manually repainted, all without success. Is this a bug? I tried the
>   same code with Teechart.Net for Winforms and it works OK so I'm having
>   doubts about the Teechart release for Xamarin.

Using the code below doesn't plot text in the NumericGauge in WinForms either. Can you please modify it so that we can reproduce the problem here?

```
  CircularGauge circularGauge1 = new CircularGauge(tChart1.Chart);
  circularGauge1.NumericGauge.Visible = true;
```

Thanks in advance.